# swig warning message with vector.i and vector of classes

Tags: c++, swig

I use swig to wrap c++ classes to ruby code. Some of my classes return `std:vector` of other classes so I use the `std_vector.i` for that.

```
%include "std_vector.i"
namespace std {
  %template(VectorString) vector<string>;
  %template(VectorField) vector<TruckBoris::Field>;
  %template(VectorStructure) vector<TruckBoris::Structure>;
  %template(VectorEnum) vector<TruckBoris::Enum>;
}
```

For the classes Enum and Structure I have this kind of warnings:

```
parser.cpp:2781:9: warning: destination for this 'memset' call is a pointer to dynamic class 'TruckBoris::Enum'; vtable pointer will be overwritten [-Wdynamic-class-memaccess]
    memset(v_def,0,sizeof(Type));
           ^
parser.cpp:2807:66: note: in instantiation of member function 'swig::traits_as<TruckBoris::Enum, swig::pointer_category>::as' requested here
    return traits_as< Type, typename traits< Type >::category >::as(obj, te);
                                                             ^
parser.cpp:4236:92: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'swig::as<TruckBoris::Enum>' requested here
    std::vector<TruckBoris::Enum,std::allocator< TruckBoris::Enum > >::value_type val = swig::as<std::vector<TruckBoris::Enum,std::allocator< TruckBoris::Enum > >::value_type>( elem...
                                                                                              ^
parser.cpp:2781:9: note: explicitly cast the pointer to silence this warning
    memset(v_def,0,sizeof(Type));
           ^
           (void*)
```

This is just some warnings and my extension is compiling and working as expected. But if there are some warnings I think it means that maybe I am wrong somewhere.

For informations:

I don't have warnings from simple classes like field but I have warning form Enum and Structure classes which both inherit from the same class. Here is the code:

```
  class TagDeclaration
  {
    public:
      TagDeclaration(clang::TagDecl * var);
      ~TagDeclaration(){}
      void setPtr(clang::TagDecl * var); //for ruby interface
      clang::TagDecl * getPtr() const; //for ruby interface
      std::string getName() const;
      bool hasNameForLinkage()const;
      bool hasLinkage() const;
      std::string getTypedefName() const;
      std::string getRaw( clang::SourceManager & sm, const clang::LangOptions & lopt) const;
      virtual TagDeclaration& Equals( const TagDeclaration & tag);
    protected:
      clang::TagDecl * m_var; 
  };
  class Structure : public TagDeclaration
  {
    public:
      Structure();
      Structure(clang::TagDecl * var);
      ~Structure() {}
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Woverloaded-virtual"
      virtual Structure& Equals(const Structure& tag);
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
      std::string getTagType() const;
      int getFieldsNumber() const;
      std::vector<Field> getFields() const;
      clang::FieldDecl * getField(int i) const;
    private:
      std::string m_tagType;
  };
```

Edit :

I can reproduce this kind of error with this:
test.h

```
class Number {
  public:
    Number()
    {
      m_num = 0;
    }
    Number(int a): m_num(a) {}
    ~Number() {}
    virtual void equals(){}
  private:
    int m_num;
};
class Float : public Number{
  public:
    Float(): Number() {}
    Float(int a): Number(a) {}
    ~Float() {}
    virtual void equals() {}
    void printToto(){}
};
class Double : public Number {
  public:
    Double(): Number() {}
    Double(int a): Number(a) {}
    ~Double() {}
    virtual void equals() {}
    void printTata();
};
```

test.i

```
%module "test"
%include "std_vector.i"
%{
#include "test.h"
%}
namespace std {
  %template(VectorFloat) vector<Float>;
};
%include "test.h"
```

extconf.rb

```
require "mkmf"
CONFIG['CXX']='clang++'
create_makefile("test")
```

Comment: You've shown a lot of code that is largely irrelevant to generating the warning, and not enough of the code that is needed to reproduce it. Can you reduce this to the smallest, complete .h and .i files possible that show the problem? Also it would be useful to know what GCC version you're using, what compiler flags you're calling it with and which version of SWIG generated the code.

Comment: As I tried to simplify I have found that the problem comes from the use of std_vector.i for vector of classes that have virtual methods. Those warnings only appears with clang++ and not g++.